# the installed apk can not connect to the cpanel data base

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I have built an android app with flutter and I have used the php and mysql as the backend on XAMMP.
after I have completed the coding I transferred all the backend files and codes to an cpanel

the app was working very well on the android studio emulator but after building the "apk" file and installing it in my android phone , the app can not connect to any of the backend.

I used the following url in all my api calls ,for instance:

```
 var res = await http
    .post(Uri.parse("https://www.mopco.ecspdm.com/users/signIn.php"), body: {
  "email": email,
  "password": password,
});
```

I have tried to run the apk on the android emulator and I have received the attached message
[image]

Comment: any logs in the run / logcat tab?

Comment: if you mean in android studio, that all I have:   Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/zygote  ( 5377): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/zygote  ( 5377): Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=47KB

Comment: when you run your apk, if there is an error with the connection then it will be logged in the logcat / run tab in AS.

Comment: I/zygote  ( 5377): After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=47KB
I/zygote  ( 5377): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB

Comment: I installed it on a physical phone not on android emulator

Comment: Check for logs related to your connection to the site, not the system ones.

Comment: sorry could you explain to me how "Check for logs related to your connection to the site, not the system ones."

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the premission for the internet connection , so I had to give this permission in the AndroidManifest file as following :

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I found that here [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest):

Add the android.permission.INTERNET permission if your application code needs Internet access. The standard template does not include this tag but allows Internet access during development to enable communication between Flutter tools and a running app.